# Use lapply to increment a variable in r

Tags: r

Is it possible to increment a variable using lapply. For the below example, how do i do it if i need the given output. or do i go for two for-loops for such problems? whats the best way?

```
 loop = 1
    string1 = "Now reading book"
    words = c("alpha","beta","gamma")

    all.words <- lapply(words,sampleFunc)

    sampFunc <- function(i,x=string1){

    temp <- paste(loop,x,i,sep="")

    }

    Ideal output
    1 Now reading book alpha
    2 Now reading book beta
    3 Now reading book gamma


    Actual output
    1 Now reading book alpha
    1 Now reading book beta
    1 Now reading book gamma
```

Comment: Why not using the row index as a helper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, `lapply()` is overkill for this task.

```
string1 = "Now reading book"
words = c("alpha","beta","gamma")
```

The simple `paste()` can do already, what you want:

```
paste(1:length(words), string1, words) # sep = " " is default

[1] "1 Now reading book alpha" 
[2] "2 Now reading book beta" 
[3] "3 Now reading book gamma"
```

Note: `string1` is a vector of length 1, while the first numeric vector and `words` are vectors of length 3. In many functions in R, what is happening is, that R multiplies/repeats the shorter vector by cycling its content over and over again. In this case, cycling over the only string "Now reading book" makes it to be repeated 3-times. That is a typical R-ish way to handle such situations. Coming from another language, this behaviour is surprising. (Python would just give an error and stop execution in such situation or cut the other two away with some warning). This, sometimes surprising and sometimes very unexpected behaviour of R makes it so hard to handle sometimes.

Just keep the concept `cycling` in mind.

The `sep = <delimiter>` comes between the content of each of the vectors which are put side to side. Somehow one thinks by this kind of 'joining' behaviour that `paste()` is a `join()` replacement. But it is actually not a flat normal `join()`. It "joins" things in parallel (as you see in the example, first elements of the given vectors side-by-side, the second elements side-by-side etc.)

However, `paste0( , collapse="")` which is syntactic sugar to `paste( , sep="", collapse="")` behaves a little like `join()` in Python does ... (when applied to R vectors, however not when applied to lists).

```
l <- list("a", "b", "c")
paste0(l)
## [1] "a" "b" "c"
v <- c("a", "b", "c")
paste0(v)
## [1] "a" "b" "c"
paste0(v, collapse="")
## [1] "abc"
paste0(l, collapse="")
## [1] "abc"

# so paste0(, collapse="") or paste(  , sep = "", collapse = "")
# applied on single vector or list behaves like python's join with separator as "" (which argument is ONE python list.
```

Answer (score 4):

`paste` is vectorized. You don't need any loop. Just use `paste` to concatenate `string1` with `words` as:

```
string1 = "Now reading book"
words = c("alpha","beta","gamma")

# Now apply paste
paste(string1, words)
# [1] "Now reading book alpha"
# [2] "Now reading book beta" 
# [3] "Now reading book gamma"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over the item number (`1:length(words)`) and then retrieve the corresponding element at that item (`words[i]`):

```
string1 = "Now reading book"
words = c("alpha","beta","gamma")
lapply(1:length(words), function(i) paste(i,string1,words[i]))
```

Comment: you can use `seq(words)` instead of `1:length(words)`